# How to find duplicates in subgroups in R

Tags: r, duplicates

I have lots of examination data of patients like this.

```
   PN CEA_VAL TEST_DAYS
1   1     2.3        25
2   1     4.6        49
3   1     5.8        67
4   3     1.8        25
5   3     6.7        69
6   4     1.9        44
7   4     3.4        87
8   5     12.4       25
9   5     16.4       25
```

PN is patients' number. CEA_VAL is the bio-test value.
And the TEST_DAYS is the time interval from treatment starts to the day bio-test conducted.

If regard every patient as a subgroup, it is OK to have same TEST_DAYS between different subgroups.

But I suspect that there are some duplicated TEST_DAYS within one subgroup.
How can I find duplicates of TEST_DAYS within each subgroup, and how can I delete them?

It is illogical to have several bio-test results on the same patient in one day.
Since the bio-tests are usually conducted again after several weeks.

Comment: If you're providing example data, it's best to include some (possibly made-up) data that actually shows the problem, e.g. an extra row for one of the patients with a duplicated `TEST_DAYS` value.

Comment: `df %>%
  group_by(PN) %>%
  filter(!duplicated(TEST_DAYS))
` using `dplyr`.

Comment: Thank you for the hints. I add another made-up patient data. And the code worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `duplicated` for each patient to get duplicated values and select only the unique ones.

This can be done in base R :

```
subset(df, !ave(TEST_DAYS, PN, FUN = duplicated))

#  PN CEA_VAL TEST_DAYS
#1  1     2.3        25
#2  1     4.6        49
#3  1     5.8        67
#4  3     1.8        25
#5  3     6.7        69
#6  4     1.9        44
#7  4     3.4        87
#8  5    12.4        25
```

`dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(PN) %>% filter(!duplicated(TEST_DAYS))
```

and `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[df[,!duplicated(TEST_DAYS), PN]$V1]
```

Answer (score 2):

If there are duplicated days for a patient, the following code should return only the first row for each day:

```
library(dplyr)

my_df %>%
  group_by(PN, TEST_DAYS) %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  ungroup()
```